# Converting a 1d array into 2d matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix

I am making a map editor where you can choose the size of `X` and `Y`.

In my example I will be using a `6x6` board. With Tkinter my values are stored in a dictionary and comes out in an array in this format:

```
{(0,"floor"), (1,"floor"), (2,"wall"), ..., (35,"wall")}
```

What I want to do is to have the values in the format of a two dimensional array:

```
{([0,0],"floor"),([0,1],"floor"), ([0,2],"wall"), ..., ([5,5],wall)}
```

Here is draft code I am trying out, but doesn't seem to work like I want:

```
valueX = 6
valueY = 6 
totalSize = valueX * valueY 
matrix = []

for i in range(totalSize): 
    matrix.append([i/valueX,i%valueY])
```

This works for a `6x6` matrix, but when I try an irregular size like `6x10` it doesn't get the results I want.

Here is the result I want:

```
[0,0] [0,1]...[0,9],[0,10],[1,0]...
```

Here is what I get:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [1, 8], [1, 9], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work."  What behavior are you seeing?  What behavior are you expecting?

Comment: I'll note you're misusing 'two dimensional array'. Your expected output is still an array of tuples, each of which has as  it's first element coordinates of where it exists in a two dimensional plane. Your outer data structure is still a single dimensional array.

Comment: @NathanielFord I think representing a multidimensional array as an array of arrays is common enough to be understood without further clarification.

Comment: @thomasd But that is not quite what he's doing. His datastructure is `[tuple, tuple, ..., tuple]`: that is a linear list that *does not end when a new dimensional direction is incremented*. The latter would look more like `[[tuple, tuple, ... , tuple],[tuple, tuple, ..., tuple], ..., [tuple, tuple, ..., tuple]]`. This question would be more correctly titled "Tagging each element in a list with the element's coordinates in two dimensional space."

Comment: I'm confused by your data types. You claim your data is stored in a dictionary, but that has no key-value pair. What you have there is a set.

Answer (score 1):

Your computation for coordinates is incorrect - I believe this should work better:

```
matrix.append([i/valueY, i%valueY])
```

The first coordinate needs to be your X value, which will increment once for every "valueY" tuples in the list, so that is divided by valueY.

The second coordinate needs to be your Y value, which is in the range 0 to valueY-1, so i modulo valueY takes care of that.

I assume the code was a simplified example, since it doesn't attempt to handle the source data tuples at all.

Comment: If the coordinates are row-column, then the first element should be Y.

Comment: @cricket_007 The coordinates in the samples given are column,row but with row incrementing first.

Comment: I understand. Accessing a 2D list would be `[row][column]`, though. I suppose I'm confused on the terminology of the question because it isn't a true X-by-Y matrix, but a 2-by-(X*Y) matrix.

Comment: @cricket_007 Doesn't seem to be a 2D list, based on the samples, just seems to be a list that maps a linear index into tuples containing coordinate pairs in a specified order.  Note that this seems to be due to Tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Matt Jordan. Just make sure you are ensuring an int output from those operations:

```
    matrix.append([int(i/valueY), i%valueY])
```

, Python 3 will give you problems if not (and even 2.x if you import division). Also you can always follow the more "intuitive" way of building such an iterable (although slower):

```
    matrix = []
    for x in range(valueX):
        for y in range(valueY):
            matrix.append([x,y])
```

You can change the order of the loops if you want to run lines of X first, and Y second.

Comment: Just to note, Python 2 always does integer division. In Python 3, rather than doing `int(i/valueY)` you can do `i//valueY` which achieves the same result.

Comment: Actually it was fairly common, at least for me, to use the "from __future__ import division" in my Python 2 scripts, thus my suggestion. The i//valueY is in fact cleaner, good idea.

Answer (score 0):

First, lets clear some things up. A dictionary in Python without keys is known as a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). In the REPL:

```
>>> x = {1,2,3}
>>> x
{1, 2, 3}

>>> x = {1,2,3,1}
>>> x
{1, 2, 3}
```

We can see that a set will remove duplicate items. We have to be careful when we are talking about sets (which at their most general do not have an ordering and do not have duplicates) and when we are talking about [lists](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html) (which have an order and can contain duplicates).

Secondly, a 'two dimensional array' implicitly indicates where an element exists in a two-dimensional plane (commonly referred to as a 'matrix'):

```
>>> y = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]
>>> y[0][1]
'b'
>>>y[1][0]
'd'
```

This is subtly different from what you're constructing:

```
>>> z = [([0,0], 'a'), ([0,1], 'b'), ([0,2], 'c'), ([1,0], 'd'), ([1,1], 'e'), ([1,2], 'f')]
>>> z[1]
([0, 1], 'b')
>>> z[3]
([1, 0], 'd')
```

Therefore it is *very important* do define what you want your function to do. Either:

```
f(list of tuples) -> (list of tuples, with each tuple being tagged with it's coordinate)
```

Or:

```
f(list of tuples) -> (list of list of tuples, with each tuple having it's original index)
```

If the former:

```
new_list = list()
xDimension = 6
yDimension = 6  # Not actually used!
for (idx, element) in original_list:
    y = int(idx / valueX)  # rounds down
    x = idx % valueX
    new_list.append(([x,y], element))
```

Note that the above does not have the problem of the list being mismatched in length. Each tuple will be tagged with a coordinate, regardless of whether the original list 'fits' in the desired matrix size. Further, if it is too short, no errors arise. This is because we are simply iterating through the original list.

If the latter:

```
xDimension = 6
yDimension = 6
matrix = list()
for y in range(yDimension):
    row = list()
    for x in range(xDimension):
        idx = y*xDimension + x
        row.append(original_list[idx])
    matrix.append(row)
```

This does have the problem that the `matrix` might not contain all elements in the original list if it runs out of space. However, it will arrange the tuples in a multidimensional array of the desired size.